# Architectural/Pattern question - problem when hiding implementation details behind interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, transparency, factory

I have a couple of classes BitMask & BitMaskLarge that both implement an interface IBitMask that exposes functionality to perform bitwise logic operations, etc.  The BitMask class contains the a private _mask field of type long and the BitMaskLarge class contains a private  _masks array of longs.

The end user works with IBitMask and the implementation details of each of the classes should be transparent to them, such as how the bitwise logic is implemented when both inputs are of one type as opposed to of one type each.

When creating an IBitMask a BitMaskFactory is used that returns the appropriate type, based on the bitwidth passed into the constructor.

The problem occurs when setting a bit in the bit mask using the SetBitIndex method.  If the bit is outside the bounds of the current mask, BitMaskLarge simply adds another element to _masks and sets the appropriate bit.  However BitMask cannot go beyond 64 bits and so need to convert to a BitMaskLarge.  Obviously this is impossible when calling bitmask.SetBitIndex(100) on the BitMask class, which should set the bit at index 100.

One possible solution I can think of would be to make SetBitIndex internal, and to create a static method on the BitMaskFactory that returned the new or updated IBitMask.  This is not ideal as it is not natural to use.  If anyone has a better solution to this problem, I’d like to hear it.  All ideas are welcome, no matter how fundamental the changes required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make types implementing `IBitMask` immutable, and have mutating operations return a new instance. This would run like this:

```
IBitMask mask = BitMaskFactory(...); // assume mask is now a BitMask
mask = mask.SetBitIndex(100); // now mask is a BitMaskLarge
```

Making the instances immutable also offers thread safety "for free".

If you find this inconvenient, you can solve it by adding another layer of abstraction:

```
class BitMaskImplementation : IBitMask {
    private IBitMask mask;

    // BitMaskImplementation defers all operations to mask,
    // and you can change the object stored inside mask without
    // your callers knowing anything about what happened.
}
```

This loses you the thread safety though.

**Update:**

You shouldn't really go to all this trouble unless a `BitMaskLarge` is much more expensive for you than a `BitMask`, *and* you also expect nearly all masks to be simple `BitMask`s.

Comment: If you do it the immutable way, I would strongly suggest renaming the method to `WithBitIndexSet` rather than just `SetBitIndex` so that nobody thinks that the "Set" method mutates the object.

Comment: I think this may have a performance hit - needing to create a new bitmask everytime.  90% of the time, the bitmask will be less than 64 bits and so an update will be fine.  This situation is to handle the minority of cases that need to be promoted to a BitMaskLarge.

Comment: @Darius: the `BitMaskImplementation` part will not have a performance hit if `mask` simply returns itself from `SetBitIndex` when it does not need to be promoted. In any case, your question asks about an architectural decision, not about implementation details.

Comment: Good point Jon. This is looking like the best solution.  I'm gonna go with it - will let you know how I get on.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between BitMask and BitMaskLarge that has been described is the use of the _mask vs _masks field. If this is truly the only difference how about always returning a BitMaskLarge from the factory? In the case were you don't need more then one long then you will only have one long in the _masks array.

Comment: This is how the BitMask class was originally developed - my remit was to improve performance (this is being used to replace a very unperformant boolean based solution for dynamically adding columns into grid on a front desk trading app).

Comment: Can you post the code so that we can get a better idea of where the performance hit is exactly?

Answer (score 1):

How about a frontend and a backend class? The frontend class would provide the actual facade for client applications to use (a role currently covered by your `IBitMask` interface). The backend class would provide the actual implementation. The frontend would then simply delegate all calls from the client application to its internal backend instance, and could transparently replace the implementation, if the bitset grows to large for the "small" version (or becomes small enough again to be represented by the "small" version):

```
 class BitMask {
     private IBitMaskData actual;
     public void SetBitIndex(int index) {
          actual = actual.SetBitIndex(index);
     }
 }

 // Stuff below is an implementation detail of class BitMask
 // and private

 interface IBitMaskData {
      ...
      IBitMaskData SetBitIndex(int index);
 }

 class SmallBitMask {
      IBitMaskData SetBitIndex(int index) {
          if( index < 64 ) { 
              // Set the bit actually...
              return this;
          } else {
              LargeBitMask newMask = new LargeBitMask(this);
              return newMask.SetBitIndex(index);
          }
      }
 }

 class LargeBitMask {
     ...
 }
```

(If you care enough about performance and memory requirements to make the distinction between large and small bit masks, you might, however, dislike this solution purely because of the additional overhead introduced)

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide if you want dynamically growing bitmasks or not. If you want it, then create a single BitMask class which supports growing to arbitrary sizes. It can still perform good if you have <= 64 bits, don't worry. Otherwise you have to tell the factory how large bitmask you want, and then you should disallow setting higher indexes than what the class instance was intended for.

Comment: The idea is for the implementation details to be hidden behind the interface.  The factory will allocate the right type initially based on the bitwidth passed into the constructor.  64 bits is an arbitrary length based on the size of a long and while fine initially, may outlive it's usefulness if the bitmask needs to grow.

Comment: It has nothing to do with hiding. You have to define the behavior in the interface: either state in the documentation that the created bitmasks can grow, and then provide an implementation which lets them grow, or state in the documentation that they are fixed in size, and then provide an implementation which returns small or large bitmasks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would say this situation needs to be defended against - as it is invalid input.  If you want to be able to swap types, then you could expose `ToBitMaskLarge` and `ToBitMask` methods on the interface to force the implementing class to manage conversions.

Of course, this won't happen automatically, but it would then allow your caller to change their mind without revisiting the factory.

Comment: While I like this idea from an implementation perspective, it doesn't maintain the transparency required by the end user, who doesn't care how I implement the bitmask.

Comment: @Darius in that case your best bet is an implementation that grows and shrinks - but is otherwise just one class.  Your current idea of two classes limits your options.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider:

First, why can't you just use the BitMaskLarge 100% of the time?  If you say "performace" I would submit to you that the difference is negligible.

Second, why is "upgrading" to a different class bitmask part of the spec?  You should either limit the user to the IBitMask returned, or always use the "Large" implementation.